# Linear congruential generator gives wrong output

Tags: java, lcg

I created a linear congruential generator (LCG), but it appears to give me the wrong output.

```
// Instance variables 
private long currentRandomNumber;
private long a;
private long c;
private long m;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // perform calculations and tests here
    final long seed = 99L;
    
    // Java's java.util.Random class values (according to Wikipedia):
    long a = 25214903917L;
    long c = 11L;
    long m = 2^48L;
    
    LCG lcg = new LCG(a, c, m, seed);
    
    System.out.println("Sequence of LCG    class: " + lcg.nextRandom() + ", " + lcg.nextRandom() + ", " + lcg.nextRandom() + ", " + lcg.nextRandom() + ", " + lcg.nextRandom());
}

public LCG(long seed, long a, long c, long m) {
    currentRandomNumber = seed;
    this.a = a;
    this.c = c;
    this.m = m;
    }

// Implementation of the recurrence relation of the generator
public long nextRandom() {
    currentRandomNumber = (a * currentRandomNumber + c) % m;
    return currentRandomNumber;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Sequence of LCG    class: 28, 61, 28, 61, 28
```

I used these values of a,c and m because I read that the java.util.Random class uses these values too. But usage of this class with the same seed gives different answers. I also checked with other lcg calculators and my answers do not match these either. I have no idea what went wrong.

Comment: the way you call constructor is different from the way it is defined ("a, c, m, seed" vs. "long seed, long a, long c, long m")

Comment: `2^48` is suspicious. Why don't you just type `50`?

Comment: Thanks, but after I matched the order I still get the wrong output. Now I get 44, 9, 14, 49, 44

Comment: Please accept the answer or leave a comment for rejection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### LCG Requires a Big Modulus

One of the key of [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is that `m` should be big enough. Or, you quickly find repeated sub-sequences because modulo operation always generates repeated sub-sequences for any arithmetic progressions. If big enough, however, a repeated sub-sequence itself would be very long so it would not seem repeated.

Your

```
long m = 2^48L;
```

is 50. `^` does not do what you expect. It's `2 XOR 48` instead of 2 to the power of 48. So use

```
long m = 1L << 48;  // or (long) Math.pow(2, 48)
```

instead. Then you will get

```
Sequence of LCG    class: 2496275487794, 103243855293781, 72264694917948, -37076138618729, -26695784318378
```

#### Why Not Exactly the Same with java.util.Random

In my experience, implementations almost always come with heuristics. Here is re-implementation of your code with those heuristics used by OpenJDK 15 to generate `nextInt`eger according to [openjdk /
jdk15](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk15/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java). Especially according to [lines from 198 to 206](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk15/blob/19b8204719c50d70fa435f9484a61365258b46c3/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java#L198-L206).

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

class LCG {
    private AtomicLong currentRandomNumber;
    //private long a;
    //private long c;
    //private long m;

    private int bits = 32;
    private long addend = 0xBL;              // your `c` is here!
    private long mask = (1L << 48) - 1;      // your `m` is here!
    private long multiplier = 0x5DEECE66DL;  // your `a` is here!

    public LCG(long seed, long a, long c, long m) {
        currentRandomNumber = new AtomicLong((seed ^ multiplier) & mask);
        //this.a = a;
        //this.c = c;
        //this.m = m;
    }

    public long nextRandom() {
        long oldseed, nextseed;
        AtomicLong seed = this.currentRandomNumber;
        do {
            oldseed = seed.get();
            nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
        } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
        return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));  // your `m` is here again
    }
}

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = 99L;

        long a = 25214903917L;
        long c = 11L;
        long m = (long) Math.pow(2, 48);

        LCG lcg = new LCG(seed, a, c, m);
        Random random = new Random(seed);

        System.out.println(lcg.nextRandom());
        System.out.println(random.nextInt());
    }
}
```

You will see `lcg.nextRandom()` and `random.nextInt()` generate the same integers if you compile the code using OpenJDK 15. While re-implementing, I found that an older OpenJDK uses different heuristics.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed solve my problem. I have one follow up question though. I read somewhere that the numbers I use are the same as the java.util.Random class uses, but when I print them next to each other they differ. How is this possible? I have tried this with Random.nextInt() as well as Random.nextLong().

Comment: @Wilko I made an edit. If you have hacker's mind, just hack it. Please check the edit and accept it. :)

Comment: @Wilko Thank you too buddy :)